# What is the difference between mediaplayer.create() and mediaplayer.prepareAsync()?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have used the following code:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse("file://"+filePath));
mp.start();
```

This works fine. Then I wanted to play music from a folder

```
mp.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("file://"+filePath));
mp.prepareAsync();
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
```

Are there any performance differences between the two method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, create method inits object in main thread. So code lines below it should wait for create.

On the other hand, prepare asynchronous opens a new thread to init object then notify you to run next operations while main thread run other lines.

Edit: As @CommonWares mentioned in the comment, `mp.create()` is a convenient method of calling `mp.setDataSoucer()` + `mp.prepare()` at the same time

Answer (score 4):

You can check `MediaPlayer` [create() source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/media/MediaPlayer.java#MediaPlayer.create%28android.content.Context%2Candroid.net.Uri%2Candroid.view.SurfaceHolder%29) to see the difference:

```
 public static MediaPlayer create(Context context, Uri uri, SurfaceHolder holder,
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes, int audioSessionId) {

    try {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        final AudioAttributes aa = audioAttributes != null ? audioAttributes :
            new AudioAttributes.Builder().build();
        mp.setAudioAttributes(aa);
        mp.setAudioSessionId(audioSessionId);
        mp.setDataSource(context, uri);
        if (holder != null) {
            mp.setDisplay(holder);
        }
        mp.prepare();
        return mp;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
        // fall through
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
        // fall through
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        Log.d(TAG, "create failed:", ex);
        // fall through
    }

    return null;
}
```

Basically `create()` call is synchronous (it internally calls `prepare()`) and `prepareAsync()` is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks. Great info.

Comment: May be a silly doubt..  

  what is difference in `MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();` and then set attribs and `MediaPlayer.Create()` ?

Comment: @unknown what kind of differences? As you can see `create()` do many more things than just simple object creation. It prepares content from given URI. What is the most important it is synchronous method so if you run it on the main thread it would freeze your UI. I prefer to use `new MediaPlayer(`) and `prepareAsync()` as this is more flexible. Basically it depends on your use case. BTW I would suggest to use `ExoPlayer` for video playback https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Answer (score 3):

The first approach ties up whatever thread you are on, long enough for `MediaPlayer` to read in the metadata of the media and prepare some buffers. If this is the main application thread, it means that your UI will be frozen while this is going on.

Comment: so the first method is method a combination of `mp.setDatasource()` + `mp.prepare()`?

Comment: @suku: That, plus creating an instance of `MediaPlayer` on which to call `setDataSource()` and `prepare()`. `create()` is just a convenience method.